# Safari browser tags for iPhone and iPad

Tags: browser, safari

Is there a way to determine if a Safari browser accessing a website is running on iPhone vs iPad? I don't want to load a mobile site on the iPad

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but this appears to be correct:

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod'))
{
    header('Location: http://yoursite.com/iphone');
    exit();
}
```

This site also has a javascript example:
http://davidwalsh.name/detect-iphone

For a longer explanation you may find this blog interesting:

http://www.bionicworks.com/php/detect-ipads-safari-browser-and-redirect-to-html5-page

Comment: I have used that php and it works as expected. Also, my version of the JS is: `var iphone = ((window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPhone'))||(window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPod')))?true:false;
var ipad = (window.navigator.userAgent.match('iPad'))?true:false;` and then set `window.location=somepage.html` based on which is true